# Conexão entre MySQL e FireDAC fecha a aplicação ao ser ativada

Tags: mysql, conexão, delphi-xe6, firedac

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que usa o FireDAC para se conectar ao MySQL. Porém quando tento abri-la em uma estação, no momento em que é setado o `Connected := True`, a aplicação é fechada, sem retornar nenhuma Exception. Envolvi o código em um `try...except`, mas mesmo assim não mostra nenhuma mensagem de erro. Aqui está o código que uso para a conexão

```
procedure TfrmServidor.confConnection;
begin
  with conMySQL do begin
    DriverName := LeXML.Strings[5];
    Params.Add('Server=' + LeXML.Strings[3]);
    Params.Add('Port=' + LeXML.Strings[4]);
    Params.Add('Database=' + LeXML.Strings[0]);
    Params.Add('User_Name=' + LeXML.Strings[1]);
    Params.Add('Password=' + LeXML.Strings[2]);
    ShowMessage(Params.Text);
  end;

  try
     conMySQL.Connected := True;
  except
     on e : Exception do
       ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Onde `LeXML` é uma função que lê um arquivo XML com as propriedades de conexão e retorna os valores em uma TStringList.
O que fiz de errado? O `ShowMessage` com o `Params.Text` retorna o seguinte:

```
[Window Title]
Servidor

[Content]
DriverID=MySQL
Server=10.1.1.16
Port=3306
Database=treinamentos
User_Name=treinamentos
Password=masterkey


[OK]
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para corrigir o problema de conexão do FireDAC com o MySQL, basta, na estação, salvar os arquivos `libmysql.dll` e `libmysqld.dll`, ou dentro da pasta com o executável da aplicação ou dentro da pasta System32 do sistema.
As DLLs devem ser compatíveis com as da sua versão do MySQL, portanto sugiro copiá-las da pasta LIB do caminho de instalação do MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Passei pela mesma situação com o Firedac, sua exception está errada.
O Firedac só aponta o erro quando você utiliza o except abaixo:

```
except on E: EFDDBEngineException do
  ShowMessage(E.message);
```

Se você estiver utilizando a versão Firedac 8.0.5.3365 altere EFDDBEngineException para EADDBEngineException.

Após descobrir o código do erro ficará fácil resolvê-lo!

Espero ter contribuído, boa sorte!